# Float to IEEE-754 in split to two 16 bit words

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, byte

I need to end up with two words (each word is 16 bit) of the IEEE-754 representation of a Python float. 
These words need to be passed to a function as ints.

When I do what Im using now I sometimes get too big ints.

`OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

This is the code im using now:

```
def floatToWords(self, value):
        s = struct.pack('f', value).encode('hex')
        word1 = int(s, 16)
        word2 = int(s[2:4], 16)
        return word1, word2

words = self.floatToWords(concentration)
modbus.write_input_register(self.modbusAddress['concentration'],   words[0])
modbus.write_input_register(self.modbusAddress['concentration']+1, words[1])
```

Am I converting it correctly?

PS: Python 2.6

Comment: Try using `word1 = int(s[0:2], 16)`.

Comment: @martineau: Should probably be `int(s[0:4], 16)` (and `int(s[4:8], 16)` for the second word).

Comment: @Mark: No, that's the same as the `int(s, 16)` currently there.

Comment: @martineau: `s` is a string of length 8. (One 16-bit word = 4 hex digits)

Comment: @Mark: Oops, that's right, I was thinking of `struct.pack('f', value)` without the `encode()`.

Comment: What order do you need the words in? Should `word1` be the high word (containing the sign bit, exponent, most significant significand bits), or should it be the low word (least significant bits of the significand)?

Comment: Another question: Python floats are (assuming a typical platform) double-precision IEEE 754 values under the hood. Do you definitely want to convert to single-precision first?

Comment: What am I missing? Python doesn't support single precision, as I understand it. IEEE-754 doubles are 64 bits. Is it that you want to convert to a 32-bit IEEE-754 and then split that?

Comment: @BillBell: I guess so. Note that Python's `struct.pack('>f', value)` _does_ do an implicit conversion of `value` to single-precision (assuming that `value` is a regular Python `float`).

Comment: @MarkDickinson: How do we know that the big endian in '>f" is needed?

Comment: @BillBell in my solution, using little endian in pack and unpack swaps word1 and word2. I don't know if the machine's endianness interferes.

Comment: @Gribouillis: Thanks for responding. On my box, '>f' and 'f' definitely give different results. Black magic!

Comment: @BillBell On mine, `f` and `HH` give the same result as little endian `<f` and  `<HH`, that's to say word1 and word2 swapped. But if you want the sign bit in word1, you must use big endian. Try with pi and -pi for example.

Comment: @BillBell: We don't. That's why I asked the OP about the desired order of the words.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I meant in the case where '>f" does 'an implicit conversion to single-precision'.

Comment: @BillBell: Oh, sorry; I just don't like using `struct.pack` without an explicit endianness specifier, but that doesn't matter here. Any of ">f", "<f" or just "f" will involve an implicit conversion to single-precision.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I suspect it makes a difference; see https://pastebin.com/SMntrZ8k. There is only one way of producing the last variation and that's what's in the one current answer.

Comment: @Gribouillis: I've tried all of the combination; see https://pastebin.com/SMntrZ8k. I'm just glad I never took up particle physics.

Comment: @BillBell: You could try reading the struct module docs. They explain all of this.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: It does, and it doesn't.

Comment: @BillBell Originaly, I chose big endian because textbooks about IEEE-754 write bits from left to right, the sign bit being the first one. I then validated my choice experimentally.

Comment: @Gribouillis: The last time I concerned myself with F.P. sign bits would have been in about 1967 on 60-bit CDC 6000-series machines. I expect them to be the leftmost bit but I wanted to see how it's reasoned out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have good reasons to think that the correct way is

```
word1, word2 = struct.unpack('>HH', struct.pack('>f', value))
```

I once wrote a [toy module](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/422746/convert-between-various-ieee754-floating-formats) on IEEE 754 and it gives compatible results.

Comment: J'espère que vous allez continuer à gribouiller.

Comment: Thanks its what i wanted